# How to record audio while taking pictures in android?

Tags: android, android-camera, android-audiomanager, android-audiorecord

Planning to develop an android application in which it has to record audio while taking pictures. When viewing it in gallery it has to play the recorded audio as well pictures.How to sync audio while taking pictures?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better use asynchronous task. So u can make both capture and record audio at the same time